# Weakening of the shadow

Tags: javascript, three.js

There is a tree with alpha leaf textures. The falling shadow strongly darkens the leaves "below", which is why the model itself becomes dark.

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

Is there any way to avoid this blackout without affecting the rest of the shadows?
[Demo](https://minov.pw/3Dmodel/?model-1) and code in the same place

Comment: I was going to suggest adding AmientLight, but I can see in the [source](https://minov.pw/3Dmodel/public/js/app.js) that you already have. If you don't want shadows on the tree, maybe set `.receiveShadow` to false on them... Having said that.. how it is now looks pretty good to me.

Comment: @2pha, In this case, the shadow of the leaves on the plane will disappear, so this, alas, will not work. :(

Comment: Do you want the shadow to not be cast on the tree? Then you can do what 2pha said, `tree.receiveShadow = false;`

Comment: @Anye, No, I want the shadow of the leaves not to darken the rest of the leaves so much.

Comment: So just slightly, not completely?

Comment: @Anye, Yes, I think if it was possible to do `shadow.opacity = .5` would be perfect)

Comment: Okay... take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **`shadowMaterial`** that is invisible but only renders shadow. You can set its `opacity` to mimic shadow darkness, here is a demonstration:

```js
var planeMaterial = new THREE.ShadowMaterial();
planeMaterial.opacity = 0.5;
var shadowPlane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, planeMaterial );
shadowPlane.receiveShadow = true;
```

**Drawback**: In older releases there has been a `shadowDarkness`-property that has been removed. Now you need extra geometry and material to emulate what has been a simple property.

Comment: I came across such a solution, but I didn't quite understand how to apply it in the conditions that the model is loaded from .gltf file.. Can you tell me how to apply it for a separate mesh?

Comment: Well, this is *one* solution. Another great way is to use spotlights with various intensities to dim the shadow on the model. You can also use ambient lights. Make sure to play around with the type of light and intensities!

Comment: Oh, it's sad. It was planned to use this as a program to display the model, i.e. the models can be different, placing the light over some individual meshes will not work. I will look for other options. Thank you for the answer, I will mark it as correct for your responsiveness)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I created another DirectionLight (slightly less bright than the main one, with a shadow) that only illuminates, on the opposite side from the main one, thereby it highlights the shaded places.

It's a stupid idea, but it helped me.